# I have a full screen android DialogFragment with a RecyclerView and an extended RelativeLayout. How do I pass the RV to the extended RL no static?

Tags: android, class, android-recyclerview

I want to have access to the RecyclerView in the Extended RelativeLayout so I can scroll etc the RV from the extended RelativeLayout.

Thanks

I don't know how to pass the RV in the constructor of the extended RelativeLayout

Comment: Could you please include a code snippet so we can see what you mean with "extended" RelativeLayout, and what you mean with "pass" the RV to the RL?

Comment: Hi Omar, thanks for the reply, I have it all working fine if I make the RecyclerView (RV) static in the adapter but I was wondering if it is possible to pass a reference to the RV in the constructor of the extended RelativeLayout (RL) I am developing a TV app that uses an Extended RelativeLayout for drawing the cursor on screen and react to keyboard inputs DPAD_DOWN etc. Like I say it works fine with the static RV but I don't like leaving objects around and making it difficult for the Garbage Collection (GC).

Comment: I don't fully understand the purpose of passing the RecyclerView to the custom RelativeLayout class you have, however, if I understand correctly, you could obtain a reference to the RecyclerView like this: 
val rv = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerviewid)
then initialize your RelativeLayout, and then pass the variable rv to the RelativeLayout instance. (something like rl.setRecyclerView(rv) )
That way you have a non static instance of the RecyclerView in your RelativeLayout class.

Comment: Thanks again Omar, apparently it ok to use a static RecyclerView in a RecyclerView.Adapter after onAttachedToRecyclerView. I was just wondering if there was a better way.